# Azure V1 functions not logging any requests to App Insights

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I'm not sure if I'm missing anything here, but what I'm doing is pretty simple & OOB thingy. I have created a dotnet azure function app(which by default creates as v3), changed the configuration to V1 and created a new http trigger function. When I run the function, I'm expecting to see the requests details in App Insights (I'm sure app insights is enabled during the function app creation). Nothing is appearing in the app insights and so the counts of number of executions also not coming. when I changed the function app run time to V3, it is all working again.

Do I need to do some thing different to get App Insights work with V1 functions?

Thank you
-Srikanth
[image: Live metrics shows it triggered an hour before]

[image: the monitor shows 0 invocations]

Comment: I followed your steps and did a test, App Insights is working fine. You can wait for a while, it may take a while to work.

Comment: @FrankGong thanks for that. It's been close to an hour now. no luck :(

Comment: @FrankGong added screenshots in the question. The first screenshot shows the live metrics showing trigger happend almost an hour back but the second one which is taken from monitor of function shows 0 invocations

Comment: There seems to be no problem on my side. I suggest you rebuild a `Function App` and repeat the above steps to see if there are still the same problem. After changing v3 to v1, please [save and refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1FCC.png) to see if it is successfully changed to v1.

Comment: I can see it is changed to V1 in configurations. Also, this is plain sample function app.. no custom code/no additional libraries. I'm talking about brand new function app with the default HTTP trigger function example.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, After raising a support ticket, It turns out to be some problem with UK West region App Insights. If I shift to some other region (so far checked for Central US & UK South) it is working as expected.

Just in case if any one facing the same problem :)

-S